# How UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad will response to iPad mini

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to know if the code below will return iPad in case the device it's an iPad mini and not a regular iPad:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
{
  // The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.
}
else {
  // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
}
```

Comment: Please copy the code into the question instead of using an image. The image host is blocked in some places, limiting the usefulness of your question.

Comment: Will do in few moments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will.  Taking a look at the definition of `UIUserInterfaceIdiom`, there are only two options, each stating that they represent a style of UI. Only iPad makes sense in the context of an iPad mini.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIUserInterfaceIdiom) {
#if __IPHONE_3_2 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
    UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone,           // iPhone and iPod touch style UI
    UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad,             // iPad style UI
#endif
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Also, you may take a look at [this useful lib](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension) to see some more possibilities of device detection

Comment: Thanks, but all I need to know is if the code above will response as iPad when the actual device is iPad mini, according to you, it will, I hope you are correct lol